# Weird behavior of the MLCC capacitor after soldering

Tags: capacitor, mlcc

It's my first time using [this](https://datasheet.octopart.com/CL31A106KAHNNNE-Samsung-Electro-Mechanics-datasheet-11805919.pdf) capacitor. Before soldering, the capacitance measured only around 6uF. But after soldering and desoldering, the capacitance became 9uF around, and stable.

I tested several, all behave similar.

So, is this normal?

Comment: It is only rated X5R, so you 'cooking' it changes the molecular structure of the dielectric, thus a permanent change in capacitance. For a very stable capacitor use the NPO types. Even X7R is a bit better.

Comment: Is it designed like this? The 6uF reading before soldering apparently beyond 10% tolerance. But the reading after soldering seems more reasonable.

Comment: What was coded by the PN?

Comment: What is the circuit you're soldering it into? If there is other capacitance in the circuit, that will affect the measurement.

Comment: @DanLaks "after soldering and *desoldering*", far as I can tell OP is testing it out-of-circuit.

Comment: Might just be that the tinned ends of the cap make better contact with your probes?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum: I will check that latter.